# I'm having problems using firebase in my project, I can't tell if it's from react-navigation or something different

Tags: firebase

Adding Firebase to my project

```
  var firebaseConfig = {
     apiKey: "XXX",
     authDomain: "XX.firebaseapp.com",
     databaseURL: "https://XX.firebaseio.com",
     projectId: "X",
     storageBucket: "",
     messagingSenderId: "654358053847",
     appId: "1: 654358053847: web: acc2a97cf872863a"
   };
firebase.initializeapp (firebaseconfig);
```

I get this error:

> Bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module '@
>   react-native-community / async-storage' from 'C: \ ... \ node_modules
>   \ @firebase \ app \ dist \ index.rn.cjs.js ': Module' @
>   react-native-community \ async-storege 'does not exist in the Haste
>   module

I have used Firebase before, but I did not understand such a problem.

Comment: Having your API key visible is very dangerous.

Comment: Also, try removing your node modules folder and re-doing `npm install` or `yarn install`

Comment: unfortunately I tried too much even the firebase version got back the same result

Answer (score 0):

Answering as an update, version 6.2.2 was recently released, which should fix your issue. See the github issue below for more info.

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/1898